# Facing issue while trying to pause the setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

In my JQuery, I have a some code that goes to database after each time interval mentioned in my Web.config...I have a button as well, on clicking 
the button should stop the current SetInterval to 10 seconds... I am using below mentioned code..

```
window.setTimeout(MyFunction, 10000);
```

MyFunction is the callback

```
function MyFunction() {
    window.setTimeout(MyFunction, 10000);
}
```

Controller Actions

```
public JsonResult GetUpdates()
{
}
```

Confusion is It still going to the database again.

Comment: So how are you stopping that process?

Comment: @mattytommo I want to pause it for sometime

Comment: You can't pause it, you'll have to add and remove the timeout.

Comment: @mattytommo can you suggest any modification for add/remove timeout in the above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Interval = window.setTimeout(MyFunction, 10000);

ClearInterval(Interval);

    setTimeout(function () {
        //Code
    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pause the function execution you could have a condition inside MyFunction which is checking whether a button is clicked and not register another `setTimeout` callback:

```
function MyFunction() {
    if (window.pauseExecution) {
        return;
    }

    // do the processing here ...

    // schedule another call in 10 seconds
    window.setTimeout(MyFunction, 10000);
}
```

and when you click on the button simply set the `window.pauseExecution` global variable to `true`. And if you want to *resume*, set it to `false`.